# List in python get single line

Tags: python, list

I have this list, in console:

```
{'Composer': 'Leighton Pugh'}
{'Copyright': '2016 James Becker'}
{'Part Of Set': '1'}
```

made by this code:

```
metadata = []
for output in process.stdout:
info = {}
line = output.strip().split(":", 1)
info[line[0].strip()] = ":".join(line[1:]).strip()
# info[line[0].strip()] = line[1].strip()
metadata.append(info)
```

it is list as i have this console output:

```
<class 'list'>
```

i use this to print/get data:

```
print(metadata[0].keys())
```

but how can i get the value from key the per example "Composer"? instead of [0]

Comment: print(metadata[0]['Composer'])

Comment: It sounds like you'd like a data table, in which case you might be looking into Pandas. It's a bit of a step up from your current code, but if you are going to create a table of composers/copyrights/etc, that is probably easiest to work with in the end.

Comment: @Danizavtz this gives me an error: KeyError: 'Composer'

Comment: print(metadata[0].values())  if metadata= [{'Composer': 'Leighton Pugh'},
{'Copyright': '2016 James Becker'},
{'Part Of Set': '1'}]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by, removing the info part, change the metadata to {}, making it an dicionary:

```
metadata = {}
for output in process.stdout:
    line = output.strip().split(":", 1)
    metadata[line[0].strip()] = ":".join(line[1:]).strip()
```

and using:

```
print(metadata['File Name'])
```

witch gives the correct output, thank you for the comments.